# Seems to be not working

Tags: usage

This generator seems to be not working currently. Or This generator seems not to be working currently.

Does it possibly mean that, I started few hours ago and after running 1 hour it stopped working is it right it's just a scenario.

Answer (score 2):

> This generator seems not to be working

to me, doesn't sound incorrect but is too informal,  while

> This generator seems to be not working

sounds very clumsy; although I wouldn't be too sure it's ultimately incorrect grammatically.

> This generator doesn't seem to be working

would be neutral in style, safest choice.

See [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seems+not+to+be%2Cdoes+not+seem+to+be%2C+seems+to+be+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cseems%20not%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20seem%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseems%20to%20be%20not%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The *seems not to be working* variant sounds more *archaic* than *informal* to me.